# Slicing A Numpy Array Giving Wrong Results

Tags: numpy-slicing

I have a numpy array that I am trying to slice along the first two columns and first two rows, and then set those equal to 0.

In my code you can see my attempt to try and do so. I am having no end of trouble in terms of getting the right amount of numbers to be set to 0.

```
nums = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
nums[0:2,0:2] = 0
print(nums)

The output should be 
[[0 0 0 0 
  0 0 0 0
  0 0 11 12
  0 0 15 16]]

My output is 
[[ 0  0  3  4]
 [ 0  0  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]
 [13 14 15 16]]
```

Any advice or insight as to why it is not displaying properly would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do operation like this:

```
nums = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
nums[0:2,:] = 0
nums[:, 0:2] = 0
print(nums)
```

Then output should be

```
[[0 0 0 0 
  0 0 0 0
  0 0 11 12
  0 0 15 16]]
```